# How to destroy totally RXjS Objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I've angular(4) application and I'm using `EventEmitter`'s for some events.

So, each `eventEmitter` has about ~ 50 subscriptions. And I want to know the way for quick destroy all of them.

1) I know the way when we will push each Observable/Subject object to the array, but it's really dirty way. We have a lot of ugly code in our application and my eyes are pouring blood when I see it.

2) I know another way when we can use `.takeUntil` or `.takeWhile` but it isn't solution! (Correct me if I'm wrong) Because subscribers will not respond to events, but Observer will have subscribers. (If you remember it's about ~ 50 for each observer). And subscribers will remain in memory. I'm not sure, but seems that GC can't destroy those objects. And It's really bad!

So, as I understand - we should use `.unsubscribe` or `.complete` for kill observers with subscribers. And.... how we can do it? Do you now beautiful way except arrays?

P.S. I also had thoughts regarding TS decorators for collect objects for destroy, but I haven't got success result...

Answer (score 0):

In rxjs5, everytime that you subscribe to an obsevable, the function returns an instance of Subscription which you can later on use to unsubscribe from the observable in the subscription scope. Take as example:

```
$sub: ISubscription;
obs$: Observable<any> = ... //some observable instance

method(){
   $sub = obs$.subscribe(...);//subscribe to the stream
}

dispose(){
   $sub.unsubscribe(); // now there is one less element listening to the stream
}
```

Another approach, when you have a large amount of subscriptions stored in singular variables that you will dispose in a singular method, is to store all the subscriptions in an array and then call .unsubscribe in a loop.

Normally in components you can see that `method` is either `ngOnInit` or the components `constructor` and `dispose` is `ngOnDestroy`.

PS: If you refer to the `EventEmitter` from `@angular/core`, then its sounds odd to me that you have such a big amount of elements subscribed to an `EventEmitter` instance to be honest...

Comment: Ok, but I have about ~ 10k subscriptions. How I can unsubscribe? In a look it take about 10-15 sec.